# Does IE9 supports css3 or not

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css, html5

I just developed a site in html5 and css3, but IE9 is not translating the styles at all. Looking around on the internet i see sites claiming that IE9 supports html5 and css3 for 99% - 100%.

Is this true or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that [CSS3 is not finalized](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work).

Second, as a more direct answer to your question: IE9 supports some of the features from CSS3, but not all. There's a compatability list on [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) that provides more info. Also, resources like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS) keep track of browser compatability, see for example the [text-shadow compatability list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-shadow#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: hi, i was looking for something like that, couldn't find it. thanks!